# AS3 auto allow for security sandbox?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm building a flash project that will be ran with a wrapper of some sort to give flash extra controls. The issue I'm running into is streaming video from a web domain while the .swf is located locally on the users computer. I'd rather not ask my clients to go into adobe's security sandbox and allow it them selves. Is there a way to auto allow a file to communication externally for streaming? I know an Adobe Air app named Ambience that streams mp3s. Anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Not with Flash Player.  That's the point of the security sandboxes; the user should know that your file is accessing the internet.

AIR has different security settings since the user has to go through the installation process.  Nothing special is required to access the internet in AIR.  Compiling to AIR sounds like it would make more sense for your project.